# Limit STL algorithms to N elements

Tags: c++, stl

(Inspired by a comment from nakiya)

Many STL algorithms take a range as a pair of iterators. For instance, `for_each(begin, end, &foo);`. Obviously, if `distance(begin, end) >= N`, and begin is a random-access iterator, then `for_each(begin, begin+N, &foo);` applies `foo` only to the first N elements.

Now is there a clean, generic alternative if either of these two conditions is not met?

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I guess he wants to say "only use the first N elements" when the sequence is not random-access (and therefore computing `begin+N` takes linear time with `std::advance`).

Comment: @Victor: and std::advance possibly invalidates any copies of the starting iterator value, so it's not just about performance.

Comment: @Steve: right, classic `std::istream_iterator` gotcha ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no generic full solution without changing the iterator type.

Proof: suppose that the iterator type is only an InputIterator, so `begin` actually refers to (for example) a stream, and `end` is a special-case marker iterator, which will compare equal to the "real" iterator once the real iterator has read EOF.

Then any use of `begin` to try to work out a new value of `end` to pass to the algorithm, will "consume" the original value of `begin`, since that's how InputIterators work.

What you could do is write an iterator wrapper class, such that the iterator counts how many times it has been incremented, and compares equal to an "end" iterator once it has been incremented N times. N could be a template parameter, or a constructor parameter to one or other of the iterators.

Something like this. I've tested it compiles and works for me. Still to do - I'm currently only handling one of your two situations, "not a random-access iterator". I don't also handle the other, "distance < N".

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename It>
class FiniteIterator : public std::iterator<
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category,
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type> {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type diff_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type val_type;
    It it;
    diff_type count;
  public:
    FiniteIterator(It it) : it(it), count(0) {}
    FiniteIterator(diff_type count, It it = It()) : it(it), count(count) {}
    FiniteIterator &operator++() {
        ++it;
        ++count;
        return *this;
    }
    FiniteIterator &operator--() {
        --it;
        --count;
        return *this;
    }
    val_type &operator*() const {
        return *it;
    }
    It operator->() const {
        return it;
    }
    bool operator==(const FiniteIterator &rhs) const {
        return count == rhs.count;
    }
    bool operator!=(const FiniteIterator &rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    FiniteIterator operator++(int) {
        FiniteIterator cp = *this;
        ++*this;
        return cp;
    }
    FiniteIterator operator--(int) {
        FiniteIterator cp = *this;
        --*this;
        return cp;
    }
};
```

Note that the second constructor only takes an iterator because the underlying type might not be default constructible (if it's only an InputIterator). In the case where the caller is creating an "end" iterator it doesn't use it, because it won't be valid once the other copy is incremented.

If the underlying iterator type is RandomAccess, then this wrapper isn't needed/wanted. So I provide a helper template function, that does the type deduction the same way `back_inserter` does for `back_insert_iterator`. However, in the case where its parameter type is an iterator of random-access category, the helper shouldn't return `FiniteIterator<T>`, but just `T`:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Category>
struct finite_traits2 {
    typedef FiniteIterator<Iterator> ret_type;
    static ret_type plus(Iterator it, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type d) {
        return ret_type(d, it);
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct finite_traits2<Iterator, std::random_access_iterator_tag> {
    typedef Iterator ret_type;
    static ret_type plus(Iterator it, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type d) {
        return it + d;
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct finite_traits {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category itcat;
    typedef typename finite_traits2<Iterator, itcat>::ret_type ret_type;
    static ret_type plus(Iterator it, typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type d) {
        return finite_traits2<Iterator, itcat>::plus(it, d);
    }
};

template <typename Iterator, typename Distance>
typename finite_traits<Iterator>::ret_type finite_iterator(Iterator it, Distance d) {
    return finite_traits<Iterator>::plus(it, d);
}

template <typename Iterator>
typename finite_traits<Iterator>::ret_type finite_iterator(Iterator it) {
    return finite_traits<Iterator>::plus(it, 0);
}
```

Example usage (and minimal test):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <list>

struct MyIterator : std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, int> {
    difference_type count;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(MyIterator::iterator_category).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(FiniteIterator<MyIterator>::iterator_category).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(MyIterator::difference_type).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(FiniteIterator<MyIterator>::difference_type).name() << "\n";

    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::copy(finite_iterator(a), finite_iterator(a,4), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::list<int> al(finite_iterator(a), finite_iterator(a,4));
    std::cout << al.size() << "\n";
    std::copy(finite_iterator(al.begin()), finite_iterator(al.begin(),3), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Caution: `finite_iterator(x, 1) == finite_iterator(++x, 0)` is *false*, even for a forward iterator or better. Finite iterators are only comparable if they are created from the same starting point.

Also, this still isn't complete. For example `std::reverse` doesn't work, because for the purposes of accessing the referand, `finite_iterator(x, 1)` is "pointing at" x.

Currently the following happens to work:

```
std::list<int>::iterator e = al.begin();
std::advance(e,3);
std::reverse(finite_iterator(al.begin()), finite_iterator(e,3));
```

So I'm not far off, but that's not a good interface. I would need to think more about the case of Bidirectional iterators.

Comment: I like this as a generic solution (+1) although your FiniteIterator only appears to be a forward iterator and doesn't inherit the traits of the internal iterator, eg how do you advance it n without doing so one at a time when the underlying is random-access? This could also be adapted to check for both N and end of course, like someone else asked.

Comment: @CashCow: I've now come back and done more with the class and helpers.

Answer (score 5):

There is already fill_n and generate_n, there is no foreach_n (or for_n would probably be more appropriate) but it is easy enough to write one.

```
template< typename FwdIter, typename Op, typename SizeType >
void for_n( FwdIter begin, SizeType n, Op op )
{
   while( n-- )
   {
      op(*begin);
      ++begin;
   }
}
```

You could do op(*begin++) but although it is less typing it may generate more code to copy the iterator. size_type is numeric so doing post-increment is no less efficient and here is a case where it is useful.

Comment: An actual `for` loop would save you the `{}`. +1 for the simplest solution; programming custom iterators is a drag.

Comment: You might want to deal with the case there n > size of the container.

Comment: @Glen: You could have a double-checked loop, it would obviously be more inefficient so you would want that as a different algorithm. Obviously you would pass in an end parameter as well and it would check at each stage if the iterator was equal to that end iterator.

Comment: Is the question how to limit `foreach`, in particular, to N items? Or is that just an example, and the question is as in the title, how to limit all STL algorithms to N items?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I used `for_each` as an example ( "For instance, for_each..."). If there's no cleaner alternative, I'll accept this suggestion, it can be extended to other algorithms too. But obviously I'd like a solution that also works with `std::nth_element`. I won't like having to write `std::nth_element_n`

Comment: @MSalters: `std::nth_element`, in common with most (all?) of the sorting algorithms, requires a RandomAccessIterator anyway. So for all those algorithms there's no problem to solve: if you were going to pass the iterators `begin` and `end`, you can certainly instead pass `begin` and `begin+N`. If you were also checking that `end - begin >= N`, I guess it'd be worth having a separate function for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could create a wrapper iterator type similar to `boost::counting_iterator` which would keep together both an increment and the underlying iterator, and would compare equal to an "end" iterator as soon as the increment exceeds the maximum value.